# Javascript object maxium memory size

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, v8

Currently i am doing a simple db migration through Javascript. I find myself wanting to keep track of some simple id -> object maps to make less SQL db calls.

So the question is, what is the maximum size of a javascript object in node?
Say i have a very simple table with 2000 records. I am only interested in two columns, is it possible for me to just store all these values under a plain JS object that looks like {id1: {col1: "foo", col2: "bar"}, id2: {col1: "ss", col2: "bb"}} ??

If 2000 is okay, what is the maximum that i can do?

Comment: It obviously depends on browser implementation

Comment: Why don't you just test it?

Comment: @vp_arth I was talking about node.

Comment: read `browser` as `engine`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's **NO PROBLEM**

In my app, I just store some logs in an Array instance and set a length limit of 10000;

`var maxListLength = 100000;`
This make the Array instance size reach to 50MB more or less;

And when the app is running, there may be 100 of this kind of instance, but with no problem;

What should you do is to increase memory limit for Node process in V8:

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 your_app.js
```

Comment: Thanks you've answered my question - although i can't change the --max-old-space-size stuff, i think i know what the limit is now.

Answer (score 2):

According to this issue on V8. Chrome can support no more than 2GB of object in memory.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=847

Comment: it does slow down and eventually freeze once the total memory usage reaches around 2GB. At least it was when i was doing pressure test on a large scale data visualization project in August 2017.